# Directory.CreateDirectory with permissions

Tags: vb.net, security, permissions, directory, create-directory

I would like to SET ALL permissions to True for all users of a computer, while using Directory.CreateDirectory

Could you point me a point to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you need to look at `FileSystemSecurity.AddAccessRule`